# Ruby using 100% CPU on OSX

Tags: macos, cpu, ruby

I'm doing web development and have Ruby running a bunch of tasks.. Grunt serve, Sublime plugins, Brew etc... Nothing fancy. Just some npm installs and a grunt serve command inherited from Yeoman/[Assemble](http://assemble.io/)

It recently started using 100% CPU and I'm not sure how to rescue my CPU without restarting.

Can I kill Ruby and then relaunch it?

How can I figure out what's causing the issue?

I cancelled out all the commands that were running in terminal windows and shut down Sublime Text and it is still hovering around 100% CPU usage and my fan is a blowin'.

Using OSX Yosemite, iTerm2, Ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

If you run `top -u` in a Terminal, it will show you what processes are running, sorted in descending order by CPU usage.  This should reveal to you who the culprit is (ruby or otherwise).  You should see the process ID (PID) of that process in the top output.  Then you can quit top (hit q) and do `kill pid` where pid is the pid of what you want to kill.